# Construct Quartz.Net Cron Expression for a requirement

Tags: quartz.net

I have a requirement to send email reminder to customers. I'm trying to trigger a Quartz job based on a datetime that is X weeks later after an event. In the Quartz job, I'm supposed to check for some condition whether it happened or not. If condition is false (e.g. no action from customer), I have to send another reminder Y weeks later. I then check again for the same condition, if false, I will send last reminder on a specific datetime that is known to me right at the start of this whole process.

Any idea how to construct the cron expression? Thanks

lyf

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're using C#, right? 
You can use this cron:

```
var CronReminderExpression = string.Format("0 0 9 1/{0} * ? *", (PeriodicityLength*7).ToString());
```

where PeriodicityLength is the number of weeks. I am multiplying for 7 cause there's no proper expression for weeks or, at least, I haven't been able to find it. 
You can find a cron expression builder [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/).
Quartz.net 2.0 supports a new trigger called **CalendarIntervalTrigger**. You can read more [here](http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2011/01/new-in-quartznet-20the-calendar.html).
You can chain jobs this [way](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/faq.html#howtochainjobs).